# Find tar.gz files in a folder which are older than 20 days and delete

Tags: files, find, timestamps

I have a backup script which creates a backup (in tar.gz) of my /var/www-folder in my CIFS-mount-folder.

To delete old backups which just waste memory I have created a cronjob that checks every day if a archive is older than 20 days and if necessary it deletes the specific tar.gz-files.

Here is my cron:

```
0 1 * * * find /my/cifs/mnt/path/*.tar.gz -mtime +20 -exec rm {} \;
```

Is that right? Not that there is any error in it, which deletes e.g. all files on the hard drive which are older than 20 days and not just the files in the backup folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would use the `-name` option:

```
 0 1 * * * find /my/cifs/mnt/path/ -name '*.tar.gz' -mtime +20 -exec rm {} \;
```

Also, ensure that you are finding *files*:

```
 0 1 * * * find /my/cifs/mnt/path/ -name '*.tar.gz' -type f -mtime +20 -exec rm {} \;
```

By splitting off the `-name` option, you will find files in the given directory as well as in subdirectories.  Also, if there were no archives, then `find` would report an error (rather than simply moving on without action).

Finally, you could handle filenames with unusual characters (such as spaces) by changing the ending of the command:

```
 0 1 * * * find /my/cifs/mnt/path/ -name '*.tar.gz' -type f -mtime +20 -exec rm {} +
```

Comment: Okay, I see. but my version works also, or? Is that just a "elegant" way do this?

Comment: partly: if you have no archives, then there's a problem.

Comment: Regarding to your last edit: Are "." and "-" unusual characters? I create my backup in the following syntax: (d).(month).(year)-(hour).(minute).tar.gz (e.g. 06.03.16-16.00.tar.gz)

Comment: no - those are okay.  I added the last for completeness.